# JPA one to many relation

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have simple `OneToMany` relation in my web app. I use EclipseLink 2.5.1 and PostgreSQL. My transactions are managed by glassfish 4.1.

```
public class Student

...

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "school_id")
private School school;
```

sa

```
public class School

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "school", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Student> students;
```

Save action :

```
public void process( {
    School school = baseManager.findSchoolById(1);
    Student student = new Student();
    student.setSchool(school);
    baseManager.createStudent(student);

    //to check operation result
    School school = baseManager.findSchoolById(1);  //school does not own previously saved student, why?
)
```

`baseManager` is an EJB stateless bean. `findSchoolById(int id)` find school via trivial `NamedQuery`. `createStudent(Student s)` only `persist` new student. Even I refresh my page I don't have any students in the schhol with `id = 1`. `baseManager` is located in CDI `ViewScoped` bean. Student are saved to database correctly. When I re-deploy my application previously saved data are correctly loaded to my application. What do I do wrong?

Comment: JPA caches entities, so if you don't set both sides of a relationship to keep the cache insynch with the database, this is what happens.  If you are not going to set both sides and maintain your relationships, you need to use refresh options to force JPA to go to the database on each query.  This is usually expensive and unnecessary in most applications, but there are numerous posts on disabling the cache in EclipseLink or forcing a refresh if you really want to go that route and get the behaviour you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to set both sides of the relationship.  So you'll need to add the Student to the school.

```
    public void process( {
        School school = baseManager.findSchoolById(1);
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSchool(school);
        school.addStudent(student);  //  <---- add the student to the List held by the school.
        baseManager.createStudent(student);

        School school = baseManager.findSchoolById(1);
)
```

Comment: So why `EntityManager` doesn't read this from database. As I wrote previously, students table in database is filled correctly...

Comment: As an aside, I don't think this is mapped correctly.  The way this is mapped, when a School is removed, the Remove operation will be cascaded to all the Students associated with the School.  I assume this is not desired.

What you likely need is a Many to Many like so:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Example_of_a_ManyToMany_relationship_annotation

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a typo - but to check your result the last line within `process`: `School school = baseManager.findeSchoolById(1);` obviously should return the same result as within the first line of the method.

Do you check the result with something like `List<Student> studentsOfSchool = baseManager.findeStudentsBySchool(1);`?